# If I start a new game, will my achievements (guns and clues) go back to zero?

Tags: achievements, max-payne-3

I want to complete Max Payne 3 on hard level, and need clarifications. I collected all golden guns and clues, and I don't want to loose those.

**If I start a new game, will my achievements (guns and clues) go back to zero?** Do I have to find those again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Any achievments are permanent, with respect to your account.